# AWS "Stack count" vs "Stack count for administrator account" limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, quota

CloudFormation has some limits
- Stack count (200) 
- Stack count for administrator account (20)

What exactly is the meaning of the second limit? Wouldn't I hit the second limit as the administrator and not be able to create the other 180 stacks? If the admin can not create those 180 stacks who can? Does it mean that is a create another role (with privileges to create stacks) it can create all 200 stack (while the administrator can not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be reading it wrong - I beleive it is 20 'stack sets' limit, and 200 stacks limit.

You can read more about stacksets here:

> **Working with AWS CloudFormation StackSets**
>
> AWS CloudFormation StackSets extends the functionality of stacks by
>   enabling you to create, update, or delete stacks across multiple
>   accounts and regions with a single operation. Using an administrator
>   account, you define and manage an AWS CloudFormation template, and use
>   the template as the basis for provisioning stacks into selected target
>   accounts across specified regions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html

Comment: No I have not (I am looking in my dashboard, not docs). "Stack instances per stack set" is a different limit (500)

Comment: Actually, when I click the "limit", the description says "Maximum number of AWS CloudFormation stack sets you can create in your administrator account." so you might be right (thogh the title clearly says "stack count for ...") :(